Registering a Snapshot repository on AWS Opensearch using Terraform
I am using Terraform OpenSearch Provider 1.0 to register a snapshot repository on AWS OpenSearch 1.3
provider "opensearch" {
  alias               = "manager"
  url                 = local.opensearch_endpoint_url
  aws_region          = var.region
  aws_assume_role_arn = local.opensearch_snapshot_manager_role_arn
}

resource "opensearch_snapshot_repository" "this" {
  provider = opensearch.manager

  name = "main_s3"
  type = "s3"
  settings = {
    bucket   = var.snapshot_bucket_name
    region   = var.region
    role_arn = var.snapshot_role_arn
  }
}

This code works successfully when launched locally using my personnal AWS credentials.
But it fails when launched from Gitlab CI runner running in EKS and using runner credentials.
╷
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│   For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
│ 
│   with module.opensearch_config[0].opensearch_snapshot_repository.this[0],
│   on modules/terraform-opensearch-config/main.tf line 60, in resource "opensearch_snapshot_repository" "this":
│   60: resource "opensearch_snapshot_repository" "this" {
│ 
╵

This very same CI runner can use the Terraform AWS Provider to create AWS ressources, so the CI runner is properly setup.
The problem is specific to the CI runner and the Terraform Opensearch Provider couple.
How is Terraform Opensearch Provider resolving AWS credentials? How can I debug this authentication problem?

Is there a required_providers block anywhere in your code?

A policy in the source IAM role was forbidding assuming the IAM role created for Opensearch provider.
Trying ton run aws sts assume-role before launching Terraform showed the real error message.
